# How to merge a cell into already merged cells

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently working on a project to keep track of the painting inventory. The file is almost finished but I need some help figuring this part out. I have a userform that inserts values in a worksheet and there is a macro that checks if the values inserted in columns : "DATA", "OPERATORE" and "VISIONATO DA" are equals to the ones above them (previously inserted with same Userbox) and if the values match than it merges only the cells in the columns: "DATA", "OPERATORE" and "VISIONATO DA". This only works when I have a unmerged cell above the "new" one and then the code works. However if I have an already merged cell then even if the values are the same it won't merge.

Here is the code I am using:

```
' Check if "DATA","OPERATORE" and "VISIONATO DA" values are equals to the ones above them,
' if yes then merge cells

Application.DisplayAlerts = False ' to avoid pop up message when merging cells

Dim rng1 As Range   ' "DATA"
Dim rng2 As Range   ' "OPERATORE"
Dim rng3 As Range   ' "VISIONATO DA"

' log is calculated with the following formula :
'   Dim log As Range
'   If Worksheets("Foglio2").Range("B2") = "" Then
'   Set log = Worksheets("Foglio2").Range("B2")
'   Else
'   Set log = Worksheets("Foglio2").Range("B1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
'   End If



Set rng1 = Worksheets("Foglio2").Range(log.Offset(0, -1), log.Offset(0, -1))
Set rng2 = Worksheets("Foglio2").Range(log.Offset(0, 7), log.Offset(0, 7))
Set rng3 = Worksheets("Foglio2").Range(log.Offset(0, 8), log.Offset(0, 8))

' All 3 values must be equals to the ones above them in order to merge cells, if they are not then
' nothing happens

If rng1.Value2 = rng1.Offset(-1, 0).Value2 And rng1.Value2 <> "" Then
    If rng2.Value2 = rng2.Offset(-1, 0).Value2 And rng2.Value2 <> "" Then
        If rng3.Value2 = rng3.Offset(-1, 0).Value2 And rng3.Value2 <> "" Then
        
            Range(rng1, rng1.Offset(-1, 0)).Merge
            Range(rng1, rng1.Offset(-1, 0)).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            Range(rng1, rng1.Offset(-1, 0)).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter

            Range(rng2, rng2.Offset(-1, 0)).Merge
            Range(rng2, rng2.Offset(-1, 0)).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            Range(rng2, rng2.Offset(-1, 0)).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter

            Range(rng3, rng3.Offset(-1, 0)).Merge
            Range(rng3, rng3.Offset(-1, 0)).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            Range(rng3, rng3.Offset(-1, 0)).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
End If
End If
End If

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

And here is a screen of the sheet I am insering the values with the Userform: as you can see the macro has merged the cells in the first 2 rows but even if the conditions are met it wont merge the 3rd row's cells.

[image: Screen shot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is not merging, your problem is the condition: When you merge 2 cells, lets say A1 and A2, and check the value of A2, you will see that it is empty. The value is kept only in the first cell of the merged area.

You can get the range of merged cells with the Property `MergeArea`, and the first cell (the one that holds the value) with `MergeArea.Cells(1)`. The good thing is that `MergeArea` is set even if a cell is not merged, so you don't have to check if the previous cell is already merged or not.

```
If rng1.Value2 = rng1.Offset(-1, 0).MergeArea.Cells(1).Value2 And rng1.Value2 <> "" _
And rng2.Value2 = rng2.Offset(-1, 0).MergeArea.Cells(1).Value2 And rng2.Value2 <> "" _
And rng3.Value2 = rng3.Offset(-1, 0).MergeArea.Cells(1).Value2 And rng3.Value2 <> "" Then
    
    Range(rng1, rng1.Offset(-1, 0)).Merge
    Range(rng1, rng1.Offset(-1, 0)).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    Range(rng1, rng1.Offset(-1, 0)).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter

    Range(rng2, rng2.Offset(-1, 0)).Merge
    Range(rng2, rng2.Offset(-1, 0)).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    Range(rng2, rng2.Offset(-1, 0)).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter

    Range(rng3, rng3.Offset(-1, 0)).Merge
    Range(rng3, rng3.Offset(-1, 0)).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    Range(rng3, rng3.Offset(-1, 0)).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
End If
```

As this is a little bit hard to read, you could put that check into a function:

```
Function compareWithPrevious(cell As Range) As Boolean
    ' Return True if cell is not empty and has same value as the cell above,
    ' even when part of a merged range.
    If cell.row = 1 Then Exit Function
    If cell.Value2 = "" Then Exit Function

    compareWithPrevious = (cell.Value2 = cell.Offset(-1, 0).MergeArea.Cells(1).Value2)
End Function
```

This would reduce the If-Statement to

```
If compareWithPrevious(rng1) _
And compareWithPrevious(rng2) _ 
And compareWithPrevious(rng3) Then 
    (...)
End If
```